# Create a dictionary from the keys of one dictionary and corresponding values of another dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, one is something like this:

```py
dict1 = {'1': ['1000', '2000', '3000']}
```

and the other is:

```py
dict2 = {'1000': ['12', '13', '14'], '2000': ['15', '16', '17'], '3000': ['18', '19', '20']}
```

Is there a way to make a new dictionary, that looks like this?:

```py
dict3 = {'1':[['12', '13', '14'], ['15', '16', '17'], ['18', '19', '20']]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using list and dictionary comprehension:

```
dict3 = {k:[dict2[i] for i in v] for k,v in dict1.items()}
print(dict3) # output: {'1': [['12', '13', '14'], ['15', '16', '17'], ['18', '19', '20']]}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to convert the keys and values to integers?

Comment: Sure, `{int(k):[int(dict2[i]) for i in v] for k,v in dict1.items()}`

Comment: When I try that I get the error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: Sorry, this one will work: `{int(k): [[int(x) for x in dict2[i]] for i in v] for k,v in dict1.items()}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do your list+dict comprehension without the redundant variable:

```
dict1 = {'1': ['1000', '2000', '3000']}
dict2 = {'1000': ['12', '13', '14'], '2000': ['15', '16', '17'], '3000': ['18', '19', '20']}

dict3 = {key: [dict2[value] for value in dict1[key]] for key in dict1}
print(dict3)
```

Output:

```
{'1': [['12', '13', '14'], ['15', '16', '17'], ['18', '19', '20']]}
```

The outer, dict comprehension iterates through the keys in `dict1`.

The inner list comprehension builds that entry's value by gathering all of the 
values from `dict2` that are referenced by the list of `dict2` keys given in `dict1`.